# PHP if statement with links

Tags: php, if-statement

I am trying to write an IF statement so that when a user is on a certain page there will be additional content displayed. I have written this:

```
<?php
if (strpos($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], 'about.php')){
        <ul class="vertical-list">
        <li><a href='/' class='button' onclick="return false;">Work Experience</a></li>
        <li><a href='/' class='button' onclick="return false;">Education</a></li>
        <li><a href='/' class='button' onclick="return false;">Skills</a></li>
        <li><a href='/' class='button' onclick="return false;">Portfolio</a></li>
        </ul>;
}
?>
```

So when a user is on the about page a navigation list will populate in the side bar but will be hidden if a user navigates away from the about page. The current code gives me this error:
`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in C:\xampp\htdocs\includes\sidebar.php on line 54`

Comment: what about this is acting in a way you did not expect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP's `strpos` returns a 0-base successful result, so you need to properly test for the "none found" result, AND you need to close and re-open your PHP tags:

```
<?php
if (strpos($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], 'about.php') !== false){ 
?>
        <ul class="vertical-list">
        <li><a href='/' class='button' onclick="return false;">Work Experience</a></li>
        <li><a href='/' class='button' onclick="return false;">Education</a></li>
        <li><a href='/' class='button' onclick="return false;">Skills</a></li>
        <li><a href='/' class='button' onclick="return false;">Portfolio</a></li>
        </ul>;
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Good - I'd appreciate you marking my answer correct if it's the one that worked for you.

Answer (score 2):

You have forgotten to actually display the HTML.  Either use `echo` or drop out of PHP to display the HTML.

Answer (score 1):

You need to close the PHP tag after the if statement, like so:

```
  <?php
  if (strpos($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], 'about.php')) { ?>
       <ul>
           ...
       </ul>

  <?php
  }
  ?>
```

You can't put regular HTML inside PHP tags unless you echo it out or close the PHP tags. I personally prefer to close the PHP tags, since it makes reading the HTML easier.

Hope that helps. Good luck.

Comment: Plus `<?php` after the `</ul>`